# React making a from into component

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui

This is my current code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Input from '@material-ui/core/Input';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  container: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  },
  input: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
  },
}));

export default function Inputs() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.container}>
      <Input
        defaultValue="Error"
        className={classes.input}
        error
        inputProps={{
          'aria-label': 'description',
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I am learning react and very new here, I am now writing a form with help of https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/

But now I am not getting how to make this code into a component so that I can use everywhere.

Can anyone help me to make this code as component?

I guess this problem very amateur but I am sorry for this. I am very new to react.

Comment: Hey! Welcome to StackOverflow! The question as it currently stands seems to be quite open-ended. I would suggest adding some details. What are you expecting to happen? What happens instead? Are there errors? Be sure to read [*How do I ask?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [*How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) from the StackOverflow Help Center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created demo with your input: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-2488e
look at Input.js